# CUBA : inject Container in Editor

Tags: cuba-platform

I have a standard ProductEdit screen extending AbstractEditor.

I am trying to @Inject the root Container of the components hierarchy, in order to walk the hierarchy and add a ValueChangeListener that would change the style.

To do so, I injected the scroll box which is the root in this case. No chance (NPE, no injection).

Then I tried upwards by calling getParent() on one of the component I injected, no parent, NPE.

How can I walk the component hierarchy with CUBA ?

Comment: It's not clear to me from your explanation, whether the injected component is null or its getParent() returns null. In general, you can traverse the components tree using Component.getParent() and Container.getOwnComponents().

Comment: Ok it works. For some reason Component.getParent() is not null anymore, probably a mistake on my side or a hot deploy issue. You confirm that Containers cannot be injected ? Also is there a way to change style of the label of a field inside a field group ? I cannot find Label instances when walking fieldgroup.

Comment: Containers can be injected as any other components. But FieldGroup is not a container. As for the questions about labels, could you start a separate topic?

Comment: Was trying to inject the scrollbox. Injection was not working very likely because of a mistake on my side (having not defined id for the container and/or using the wrong class). Giving it an Id and injecting as a Container did the trick. Starting another topic for label of fieldgroup.